# How to exit "braced scope"?

Tags: c#, break

Is it possible to exit a scope in C# like it's possible to `break` out of a loop for example?

```
private void a()
{
    // do stuff here

    {
        // do more stuff here

        break;? //<-- jump out of this scope here!! break won't work

        // this further code should not be executed
    }

    // do stuff here
}
```

Comment: Put `do` before the `{` and `while(false)` after the `}`, and `break` will work...

Comment: use the `return;` keyword

Comment: You can use `break` to break out of a loop or switch.

Comment: @Alberto that will never allow the last `// do stuff here`  to be executed.

Comment: Yeah, but you should inside some sort of iteration, a `while`, a `for`, a `foreach`

Comment: yes https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/break

Comment: What exactly are you using the scope for?

Comment: @Fildor It's just "code organizing". I did't want to create a new method (where you can use `return;`, so I made a scope. Now I ended up creating a new method.

Comment: That's the better idea anyway, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `break` to break out of a loop or switch, but you cannot break out of a simple block like this.

There are ways to achieve this, for example using `goto` or artificial `while` loop, but it definitely sounds like a code smell.

You can achieve what you want using **simple condition** which will make your intention much more clear.

Instead of:

```
DoSomething();
if (a == 1) // conditional break
{
    break;
}
DoSomethingElse();
break; // unconditional break (why though)
UnreachableCode(); // will generate compiler warning, by the way
```

You can do:

```
DoSomething();
if (a != 1) // simple condition
{
    DoSomethingElse();
    if (false) // why though
    {
        UnreachableCode(); // will generate compiler warning, by the way
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can extract this part to a separate named method and short-circuit using `return` statements. Sometimes, it really makes code more readable, especially when you have a return value:

```
private void a()
{
    // do stuff here

    MeaningfulNameToDescribeWhatYouDo();

    // do stuff here
}

private void MeaningfulNameToDescribeWhatYouDo()
{
    // do more stuff here

    if (condition)
    {
        return; //<-- jump out of this scope here!!
    }

    // this further code should not be executed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to use `goto` statements but I strongly suggest you don't use them until you gain more experience with the language. I never use goto and I don't know of any programmers who do, because it can make your code a giant spaghetti mess and there are generally better alternatives.

There's ways to use them responsibly, but from your question it sounds like you're not sure how to properly use if/else/while etc. statements. Instead it's better to use proper flow controls.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/goto